# Why doesnt click_and_hold method select text at the beginning of a paragraph?

Tags: python, selenium

why isnt the selection starting at the beginning of a pragraph??

Get link:

```py
driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)")
```

Get element:

```py
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/p[2]/b')
```

Create action chain object:

```py
action = ActionChains(driver)
```

Selecting text:

```py
action.click_and_hold(on_element = element).perform() 

action.move_by_offset(0, 35).perform()

time.sleep(4)

action.release(on_element = element).perform()
```

Comment: Or how could i put the cursor at the start of the paragraph? And highlight the text for lets say two sentences exactly?

Comment: what? i want to copy text from the start..? how do i do that? @RichEdwards

Comment: How much text are you trying to copy? Do you want 2 sentences or more? Using click and hold is not a good way of getting text from a page and using full xpaths is brittle and bad practice. Be clear in what you want and I'll help you

Comment: @RichEdwards
My question is.. what would be the best way to copy a paragraph from this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)? using selenium 

this one :


Python is an interpreted, high-level and general-purpose programming language. Created by Guido van Rossum and first released in 1991, Python's design philosophy emphasizes code readability with its notable use of significant whitespace. Its language constructs and object-oriented approach aim to help programmers write clear, logical code for small and large-scale projects.

Answer (score 0):

This works for what you have requested:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)")

firstTextBlock = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='mw-parser-output']/p[2]")

print(firstTextBlock.text)
```

The output on my console:

> Python is an interpreted, high-level and general-purpose programming
> language. Created by Guido van Rossum and first released in 1991,
> Python's design philosophy emphasizes code readability with its
> notable use of significant whitespace. Its language constructs and
> object-oriented approach aim to help programmers write clear, logical
> code for small and large-scale projects.[28]

---

Update based on the comments.

If you want this text to be available in your clipboard use [pyperclip](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/).

Install it:

```
pip install pyperclip
```

Add this to the code:

```
import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy(firstTextBlock.text)
```

Now your text can be used to paste wherever you want it.

Comment: no it does not work...it just prints it out in terminal...i want selenium to highlight it...so i can copy it @RichEdwards

Comment: That is copied. Copy means to reproduce. Its in a variable. The print shows you it's content. The text is contained within firstTextBlock.text... You're now able to do anything with it that as you want. If you want it in your clipboard you can add it to a clipboard object. If you want to write it to a file then do that. In programming you do not use highlight, copy and paste its pointlessly long winded, limited and fallible... So why copy it? What are you trying to achieve? - I did ask you to be clear...

Comment: Oh sorry..I didn't say that i want to paste it too..if it is copied now..how can i paste it to something in the browser,let's say in the box search wikipedia...I have tried this but its not working:

firstTextBlock = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='mw-parser-output']/p[2]")

search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
           EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="searchInput"]'))
                )
search.click()

search.send_keys(firstTextBlock)


pyperclip is not working also...@RichEdwards

Comment: https://imageshack.com/i/pm5y7ZWQp
Here is a picture of what i want to do @RichEdwards

Comment: Look at the print line in my answer - you access the text with firstTextBlock.text - you need to use search.send_keys(firstTextBlock.text)

Comment: Additionally "not working" doesn't help me fix stuff for you. You need to please share the error you're seeing. However, you don't need it. You wanted it copied to clipboard so I was showing you how.. I'm my other comment above, Just adding the. text  should bring you online

Comment: oh okay..thank you..got it now..but one final question..my xpath for firstTextBlock is  /html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/p[2] and yours is //div[@class='mw-parser-output']/p[2]
where did you get your xpath from? why is it different than mine ?

Comment: I created mine by a hand - I looked at the dom and typed it in devtools to test it.  If you Google "how to writr good xpaths" and do some background reading you'll see there are lots of tutorials out there. Good object identification involves creating a small, robust, unique identifier that allows you to uniquely identify the object consistently.